# WPF query builder

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

does anyone have experience on developing a query builder in wpf? (Even C# won't be a problem). I should be able to build sql queries with this query builder after integrating to the application. Please let me know if you know any resources that I can follow or any third party controls that will be helpful in this.

Comment: Do you have a limited scope on what kinds of queries you can build? Limited to where expressions and hard coded columns of a given table? Or a fully fledged query builder that dynamically maps a given database and lets you query any data source you like?

Comment: Hi Albin, thanks for your quick response. The queries are going to be simple. Mostly selects and wheres. But I need to be able to do this with any data source.

Comment: Are you looking for advice with constructing the query, or how to build a UI for it?  For the query, a good place to start would be the GetSchema method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx), which can tell you about the structure of a database and the syntax to use in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this website: [query-builder.com](http://www.query-builder.com) ....source code license, C# and WPF ready which can save you weeks if not months of coding and debugging. You can also use the freeware version and it also connects to any ODBC sources.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for your input. I actually started doing the qbuilder by my own already. It is only 3 days old and thanks for giving the info before it is too late. But the site I think is not accessible. Are you sure the URL is correct? Thanks again.